# Query templating in cypher? How to avoid repeating myself

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My group has many queries that tend to refer to a class of relationship types.   So we tend to write a lot of repetitive queries that look like this:

```
match (n:Provenance)-[r:`input to`|triggered|contributed|generated]->(m:Provenance)
where (...etc...)
return n, r, m
```

The question has do to with the repetition of the set of different relationship types.  Really we're looking for any relationship in a set of relationship types.  Is there a way to enumerate a bunch of relationship types into a set ("foo relationships") and then use that as a variable to avoid repeating myself over and over in many queries?   This repetitive querying of relationship types tends to create problems when we might add a new relationship type; now many queries distributed through the code base need to all be updated.

Enumerating all possible relationships isn't such a big deal in an individual query, but it starts to get difficult to manage and update when distributed across dozens (or hundreds) of queries.  What's the recommended solution pattern here?  Query templating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible as a built-in feature, but it seems like an interesting feature. I would encourage you to post this to the ideas trello board here:

https://trello.com/b/2zFtvDnV/public-idea-board

Perhaps suggesting something like allowing parameters for relationship types:

```
MATCH (n)-[r:{types}]->(p)
```

Of course, that makes it much harder for the query engine to optimize queries ahead of time.. A relationship type hierarchy could work, but we are incredibly hesitant to introduce new abstractions to the model unless absolutely necessary. Still, suggestions for improvements are very welcome!

For now, yes, something like you suggest with templates would solve it. Ideally, you'd send the query to neo containing all the relationship types you are interested in, and with other items parameterized, to allow optimal planning. So to do that, you'd do some string replacement on your side to inject the long list of reltypes into the query before sending it off.

Comment: This might be a terrible idea, but one way you could get around this would be to introduce very limited macros.  If I could define "FooRelationship" => foo|bar|baz|quux then you can expand macros in queries prior to evaluation (no problem with query optimization there).  Macros don't introduce any new abstractions into the model.